# datepicker on a asp text box not working after a post back event

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

```
$(document).ready( function () 
{
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'
    }).val(); 
});

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" TabIndex="8" CssClass="txtalign" BackColor="White" ClientIDMode="Static" ForeColor="Black" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**for first time load its works fine but after a click on a another button (means after a post back) it stop working.**

Comment: Is `txtDate` inside an `UpdatePanel`? Is there any server-side logic linked to `IsPostBack`? What is `.val();` call supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,it will surely work

```
 function pageLoad () 
 {
  $("#txtDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'
  }).val(); 
 }
```

jQuery does not work after any post back so we have to instantiated all the things. so we have to use pageLoad() event here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net ajax Then it can cause problems. If you are placed your datepicker inside a update panel then you should prefer not to use jquery. Then use ajaxcontrol toolkit datetime picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your script file.

```
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  prm.add_endRequest(function () {
  .
  .
  write method here
  .
  .
```

}

### You can read details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028%28v=vs.100%29.aspx